# Confusion about model.train()

Tags: pytorch

I am a beginner in pytorch. I saw on github that some deep learning models have model.train(), and some don’t, but they can run normally. I want to know if model.train() is necessary? what's the effect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`train` mode or `eval` mode only matters when you have modules that behave asymmetrically (e.g. BatchNorm, Dropout) in training/testing. I would like to emphasize that it does not affect gradient accumulation at all. Even with asymmetrical modules, one can perfectly train a model in `eval` mode. Some do this in order to save memory in training using a pretrained ImageNet model.

If you don't have any asymmetrical modules, it does not matter at all.

By default, all modules start with `training=True`.

Answer (score 2):

[`train`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.train) and its counterpart [`eval`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html#torch.nn.Module.eval) switch the model between training and evaluation mode.

In training mode, the tracked gradients are generally updated on each evaluation of the model. This is needed to perform the gradient descent used for training. In evaluation mode, they are not.